Are `Find me X` questions on topic here?
We are seeing a few questions of the type.
"Where can I find x", where x can be free market data, a paper, a trading system, or a how to tutorial.
Should we make a decision as to what types of find me x questions are and aren't on topic?
I guess the best place to start would be looking at the output from 
this search: and then deciding if these are the type of questions we want in Quantitative Finance.
